# How do I force home redirects and disable main header on a Wordpress site, by just changing the "Front page" settings?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'd like to have a blank page called "placeholder-home" with the slug "/placeholder-home" that, when set as the Front page (in WP reading settings), changes header to something basic and forces subpage redirects to home.

Answer (score 0):

To do this I created a blank page with slug "placeholder-home".
The following method compares the ID of the front page with the ID of "placeholder-home" in both the header.php and functions.php files. If matching then changes are made.

In header.php, to enable a change of menu:

```
<header>
       <?php
    //Gets the placeholder page's pagename
    $placeholderpage_slug = get_page_by_path( 'placeholder-home' );
    //then gets the ID from the placeholder's pagename
    $placeholderpage_id = $placeholderpage_slug->ID;
    
    //Gets the ID of the current front page
    $frontpage_id = get_option('page_on_front');
    
    if ( $frontpage_id == $placeholderpage_id ): ?>
            <!-- Nav for site under development -->
      <nav class="dev_site_nav">
    
         <div>
    <h3>Website under development</h3><p>Please check back later</p>
    </div>
    
    </nav>
    
      <?php else: ?>
           <!-- Nav for normal site -->
      <nav class="main_site_nav">
<!-- the content of your main navigation -->
    </nav>
            <?php endif; ?>
    </header>
```

And within functions.php, to force redirect to home:

```
//Redirects when 'placeholder-home' is set as front page
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_to_homepage' );

function redirect_to_homepage() {
        $placeholderp_slug = get_page_by_path( 'placeholder-home' );
    $placeholderp_id = $placeholderp_slug->ID;
    $homep_id = get_option('page_on_front');
    
    if ( ! is_page( $homep_id ) && $homep_id == $placeholderp_id ) {                                                                                
         wp_redirect( home_url( 'index.php?page_id=' . $placeholderp_id ) ); 
    }
    exit();
}
```

There is likely a more elegant solution to this, so I welcome comments.